# What to do with an unwanted tag in the tag list?

Tags: git, git-tag

When I run `git tag` the first line is value `2` - what is it? If it was a wrong tag record (there should not be that tag) how to remove it?

```
PS C:\Users\rozerro\StudioProjects\testing_project> git tag
2
step-1
step-2
step-3
step-4
step-5
step-6
step-7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as you suspected, you have a tag called `2`.

If you're sure you don't need it, you can remove it using the `-d` flag:

```bash
git tag -d 2
```

Comment: worth adding: if this is a shared repository and the tag exists on the remote, you will also need to run `git push origin -d 2`, and tell your coworkers to delete their own local copy of that tag (`git tag -d 2` on their own machine)